# Rails Model seems valid but doesn't validate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, validation, activerecord, model

My model looks like this, nothing fancy:

```
# Table name: invoices
#
#  id               :integer         not null, primary key
#  total            :float
#  discount         :float
#  description      :text
#  created_at       :datetime        not null
#  updated_at       :datetime        not null
#  company_id       :integer
#  secret           :string(255)
#  address_id       :integer
#  price_per_credit :float
#  paid             :boolean
```

I can create instances of this both on the server and in the rails console, and these instances return true if I call `.valid?` on them (I turned off all validation for testing purposes).

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > i = Invoice.new
 => #<Invoice id: nil, total: nil, discount: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, company_id: nil, secret: nil, address_id: nil, price_per_credit: nil, paid: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :002 > i.valid?
 => true
```

However, for some reason, I can't save these instances to the database.

```
1.9.3p194 :003 > i.save
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => false
```

Locally I'm using sqlite, the production server is running MySQL, but both show this behavior. I'm not really sure what to do to debug this. I did run `db:migrate`, and my gems are up-to-date. How can I sove this?

Comment: Try `save!`. Perhaps you'll get more info this way.

Comment: Yep, that helped a lot. I got more output, including `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved`. That was a great hint, Google led me here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/RecordNotSaved. One of my before_create filters was setting `invoice.paid` to false, but returned `false` too, causing the save proces to halt. Simply adding `nil` to the method solved the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out I had a `before_create` filter that returned false, causing the save proces to halt. To solve this, I added `nil` to the class, like this:

```
# BEFORE:
def set_paid
    self.paid = false
end

# AFTER:
def set_paid
    self.paid = false
    nil
end
```

Hope this helps others too!

Comment: Yup. Was having same issue today :)